# Cordova app performance varies greatly between Android versions

Tags: android, performance, cordova

My environment:
Android Studio 2021.3.1 
cordova 11.0.0
gradle-7.5
Android Gradle Plugin 7.2
JDK 11 (Microsoft open version) - 11.0.15 (Microsoft 11.0.15+10-LTS)
Node v14.15.0
NPM 8.1.2
Target SDK = 32

Plugins: media@6.0.0, insomnia, email-composer, wkwebview-file-xhr
Other: jquery, abcjs music notation library, fontawesome

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308888/android-performance-hit-on-later-versions-than-2-3-5-phonegap-cordova/27941624#27941624) but that was over 9 years ago and looking for any updated info and for my specific issue.

I'm struggling with a wide range of performance on different Android devices for my Cordova app. Android studio emulation for me seems to be fast on Android 7 but slow on Android 10 and unusable after that. The app works great on my Android 7 device. A friend's Android 10 device will hardly function. Android's pre-launch report gives one crash (ANR in com.android.systemui;PID: 756;executing service com.android.systemui/.dump.SystemUIAuxiliaryDumpService;) with 2 out of 8 devices having performance issues, both of them being Android 8.1, with working emulators from version 8 through 12.

Based on research, it seems the issue may be related to

1. editing html with JavaScript (due to bringing in text from external files, needing to populate data at runtime, etc) (I have 142 document.write statements. Does replacing innerHTML with jQuery have a different impact than writing a div?)
2. use of $.get (purpose is to enable use of txt files to populate the app which can be easily edited on their own and copied into different projects. It also prevents having a huge index.html file. I load approx. 1 MB of text into memory and then just replace html as needed.)
3. for loops (I use structure `var i = 0, len = importArray.length; for (; i<len; i++) {`)
4. many file references? (~9 css files, several .js files)
5. possibly use of jQuery or maybe the abcjs library (I used to load jQuery mobile but removed it, but that didn't impact performance)

The app must also be usable as a webpage to limit amount of extra effort (thus my use of Cordova), example: https://gospelriver.com/favhymns/. I also use local storage instead of databases so that it has the same functionality on the web and to make it easier to maintain the text files.

Are any of the following relevant to try to incorporate in my project? I don't know where to start with further troubleshooting.

1. Threading (can we even do this outside plugins? I see notices like "Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.")
2. Crosswalk is suggested [here](https://julienrenaux.fr/2015/08/24/ultimate-angularjs-and-ionic-performance-cheat-sheet/), but [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3) states it does not work for Android 10+ (which is a version I've seen problems with). Maybe a similar webview tool exists?
3. Conversion to Ionic - sources say that won't improve performance since it's built on Cordova
4. I've already redesigned the app once to pull in one song at a time rather than the whole hymnal into the index file, but maybe there is a different approach to coding that I need to consider based on my example https://gospelriver.com/favhymns/
5. Something else? I was hoping for a quick fix like Crosswalk apparently was at one time, but I'm not seeing it.

If the problem is deemed to be coding, I suspect I should figure out Profiler, which I tried to use and it shows "no supported devices" - but that is a separate issue. If the app doesn't hardly load to begin with though, I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to have resolved the performance issues is as follows:

- Upgrade Android Studio (2021.3.1 RC1) along with other upgrades it suggests
- Utilize proguard (File > Project Structure > Build Variants > All modules/releases > Minify Enabled = true) with a proguard rules file containing:

```
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep public class nl.xservices.plugins.Insomnia { *; }
-keep public class de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.** { *; }
```

- Replace tables with divs

Also, one user had to uninstall a conflicting app that was utilizing outlandish permissions.